# Django: Httpresponse with file object and updating field value

Tags: django, httpresponse

I'm having trouble with saving/updating a value to my database table after the Httpresponse is created and am looking for any tips, help, pointers, etc. I am passing a pdf object from my database to the browser, which works perfectly when the updating code is not in the model. With the code as below, I get a Django Unicode Decode Error. The exception states : "'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 564-565: invalid data." The odd thing is that this error does not occur when I am not trying to update the pdf_printed field (meaning no decoding error occurs normally, I get the pdf object to display without this problem), so wondering if those two methods are somehow clashing... seems like the obj.save may be the issue. Again, thanks for any insight to this issue!

I should also add that the update code manages to update the field; it just doesn't display the pdf object.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.pdf.models import ABC
from django.http import HttpResponse


class ABCAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = ['print_selected_pdf']

    def get_user(self):
        return '%s'%(self.user.username)

    def create_pdf(self, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.pdf'

        for obj in queryset:
            response.write(obj.form)
            #update the pdf_printed to true
            obj.pdf_printed=True
            obj.save()
        return response

    def print_selected_pdf(self, request, queryset):
        # prints the pdfs for those that are selected,
        # regardless if the pdf_printed field is true or false
        qs = queryset.filter(pdf_printed__exact=0)
        return self.create_pdf(qs)

    print_selected_pdf.short_description = "Print PDF"

admin.site.register(ABC, ABCAdmin)
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pdf/abc/
Django Version: 1.1
Python Version: 2.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'djangostuff.pdf']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  226.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  186.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  912.             response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_query_set())
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  694.             response = func(self, request, queryset.filter(pk__in=selected))
File "/home/user/django/djangostuff/../djangostuff/pdf/admin.py" in print_selected_pdf
  50.         return self.create_pdf(qs)
File "/home/user/django/djangostuff/../djangostuff/pdf/admin.py" in create_pdf
  43.             obj.save()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  410.         self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  474.                         rows = manager.filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
  444.         return query.execute_sql(None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in execute_sql
  120.         cursor = super(UpdateQuery, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in execute_sql
  2369.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  22.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in last_executed_query
  213.             u_params = tuple([to_unicode(val) for val in params])
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in <lambda>
  211.         to_unicode = lambda s: force_unicode(s, strings_only=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_unicode
  92.         raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)

Exception Type: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /admin/pdf/abc/
Exception Value: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 564-565: invalid data. You passed in '%PDF-1.3\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Kids [ 4 0 R 5 0 R ]\n/Type /Pages\n/Count 2\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (Python PDF Library \\055 http\\072\\057\\057pybrary\\056net\\057pyPdf\\057)\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Catalog\n/Pages 1 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/Contents 6 0 R\n/Resources 7 0 R\n/Rotate 0\n/CropBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]\n/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]\n/Type /Page\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<<\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/Contents 17 0 R\n/Resources 18 0 R\n/Rotate 0\n/CropBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]\n/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]\n/Type /Page\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/Length 4167\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nh\xde\xec[[o\xe36\x16~\xcf\xaf \n\x14\x90\x8a\xb1*\x92\xbaP}Yt\xda\xed\xec\x14\xdb\xe9l\x93\xc5b1\xe9\x83b\xcb\xb1&\x8e\x94Jr\x82\xfc\xfb=\x17\xd2\x96\x14G\xee\xb4\xc5n\x84m\x06cQ\x14/\xe7;<$?\x1e\x92_\xbe9\x97\xe2\xba={}q\xf6\xe5\xc5\x85\x12R\\\xac\xcf\xa4\x0e\xb2$5"\x84\x7f.\xac\xb2\xc0(\x91\xa4:0\xe2\xe2\xf6,\x14\xd7\xf0\xffb\x89?\x0fg\xdewe\xd3v\xe2]~[\xf8\x17\x1f\xcf\xfezq&\xe9\xfb\x1bx~\x0f\x85|\x142\x08\xd3L<\x08\x19\x8a\x1f\xc4\x87\x9fC\xb1\x82O\xa58Sq\x14D"I\xd2@\x1b\xb1P*\nb|FA\x98\x88\xa68{\xfd\x05$\xfb(\xce~\x01\xc1H\x1a\'G\x92\x04&\x12\xcb[\x8aEq\x16J\x07Rl\xcf\xce\xf7)\xa5\tR\x05\xa1?\x13\xbd\x84Dg\xff@\x1b;jYF\x07lY2r\xa6\xe5\xfd=?fO`\tq\x02\xd9"2\x00\xa8k\xa1L\x18\xa4\xd1\xb4\xc5p\xf9\x90A=\xb5\x98\xe4W\x01\xf83\xd5\xff]*k\xaf*\x08\x95\xce8\x83\rk\x19$J\xc4\xa1\x0c2g\xae\x8b \x0cU\x82\xc3\xe1\x07\xef\xed\xbb\xf3\x0b\x7f\x91\x05\xda\xfb\xe9\x9f\xdf@(\x82\xd0\xdb\x1f\xdf\x9d\xfb\x8b\x18B_\t\xff\xe7\x8b\xefq\xac\x8dx\xac5\x814:\x85\xe2/\xbe\xa5bb\x85\xc5@ Iqd\xfd\xe0}W7\xa2\xc8\x97\x1bQ\xafE\xe7/\xa4\x0c\x8c\xb7\xf1\xe1\xa7\x10\xebz\xeb/` \xf4\xb66\xbe~(m\xa8\xba~\x85U\xa7\x9e\xb8s\x1f\x8b\x9c\xaa\x06\x18*\x89\x13\xae\x11\xe5\x8em\x85\xa1\xe1\n\xdb\xc2\xc74\x9e(\xab\x95o\x82\xd8+\xb1$\xe9-9:\xf7S\xf8\xed\nz\x88G_\xeb \xf2j_C\xc2\x1d%o\xfc\x04\xbfl9\xc5=\xc5qx+jz[s\n[ \xe7\xadz_\xcaU/SE\x9fmZ[k\xc9\xa9\x05\xa7\xe3\x02\xca\xea\xda\x97\x18\x10\xdd\xc6!\xc8\xf9\xb9d\x91\xcb\xfb>\x9c\xae\xec\x1eI!\x0b\x15\x06Q\x94i\xb1\x90\xd0\xf6*\xb5zI"\xd4\x0b6I\x94\xb1b\x1e|\x19B\xee\x08t\xd9m\xb0d\xc4\x9d\xc2\xef\x8e_:\xb1\xad9\xd4\x02\x0c\x8d\x15\x91\xfc\x14u\xcd\x0fT\x18\xccu\x9eM\xb8\xa3\xfc\r\x14\x0c\x12\x89+z\x03\xa1\x13x\xdb\xdagE\x91\x80\x1f\xa4\x03\xfc\x14\'l\xf6CFz-8\xd1\x92\x13\xb1l\xb7~\x0c\xf2\x96\xdc\xf4`\x812\x8a\x0f\xc6\xa6\x9c\xb1A$A\x04\x1d\x1aH.vU\xdb\x15\xf9\xea\xd1W\x06mh\xdd\xd4\xb7b\xb9\xa9\xeb\xb6t)\xea\n\xdb\x02\xb4\x8df\xb9\xb1\xe1\xbb\x82\xeb\x81\xea\x8d2{\x13C\x05\xb2*\xe3\x88\xebi\xa0\x90\x04\x05\x8d\xe0Q\xf8\x19\xfcV h\xe6u9\xbd\x80\xb6\xf0\x8d\xbf\x88;\xfaT#\xd8\x0c\xda\x99\x9f]K-\xc1\xfd\t\xac&S=`\\#\x04R\xdb\x8b\xea\n;O\x02Bn\xfc\x85\xc6\xa2E\xbb\xcc\xb7\x1cU\x10@6\x06h\x9d\xd4d\x86\x8c!M\xd3\xbd\xa6\xb4-P\xdb^\x12~..\xbd\xaa\x16\xcb\xbaZ\x97\xab\x82t]AO\x83\xb6]\xf2\xdb\xa5/\xba\x1a\x08O\xf8\xb9\x8f-\x0e\xc9\x97\x14_\xdf\xdem\x8b\xae\xd8\xba&\xc9\xb4\xd6{U\x85N\xf0Pq=`/\xd8y\xa1\xb3\xc4\xa0\x8a\x1a\x0c+\xf3\xaa\xb5\x8fz\xc3jA\x15\xa8:\x89\n\xb9\xf4):\x10o}\x99Qg\xc2WaK\xe0\xac;\xb1\xe2\x80\xa8\xe8QsV\xec\x8bX\xd2\x8e^\x1b\xca\xc8\xbf\x05\xd5\xcb\x89;\x1c\xc3Ro\xebdb\x04@\xe02\xa9\x18\xc1\x07\xcf\x15O\x9d\x10\x8b\xc4N\x18RccA\xd8\t\xf1{\xc9Eu\xae\xa8\xb2\x12\xbf\xecl\x8e\xb6+k\xae\xf0\x15\xb6\x15\x14\xd1\xb1,.qneBYW\xb6\xd9\xa0\x0f+\xb0\xe2q\xb3EV\x9d0\xe0\x91:\xcb\xdb\xfc\x9al\x0f\x04\xc8hl\x01\x88bS?\x88%\xb5\xd2\xbe55\xb7&\xf6j\x1a\xe3p\x98\xa1\xf7\x9dx\xa8w\xb6\xf1`\xb2P&;\x98\x9dt\xad\xa7l\x7fZ\x89\xabB\x94k,\x02\x1a~\'68z\x1a\x88\x06U\xf2\xd0\x85C\x11\xb4\x89\x8b\xd8PD!\xf2%%\xb4\xb1%\xea!\xf6\xeeK\xfbN\xc5\x05h\xbc0\xa2\xbc\xf5\x95\x04U\xae\xfdA\x9b\xa8,I\x9eZ\x95\x94{\xab\xc2y\x03$\xaa\xb8\xbdX\xc1\xb7>\xe0f\xedB\xd7\xb0M\x9d\xd0\x80@\xa9Z\x9aw\xe8\xbbm\x04\xf1\x00\x19c\x97\xe7\x86\x06al\x16\xd7\xea\xb6\x9dW\xd6(j\xd1\xb7\x0f\x1e}\xa1O\xc0*\x80Z\xce\xe0$J\x12K\xed\x86\x0c\x0c\xa1\xc8P \x0emlB)\x0f\xaf8\xa3\xa2\t\xd1`_7>\x0cA\x9b\x9a>nW\xdc\xe9j\xdb\x94\nS\xd6\xa2\xad\x81Q&^?\x16\x07M64(\x03\x8b\xc8\xb1\x0eL%l\xc9\x9czG\xc5/)\xb7\xa2\xdc\x18\xbb\x86\xc8\x92\xeb\xc2,\x1c\x89\x89\xa8\x00,\xaa\x85v\xc1)kMp\x15\x8c\xd3Q\xa8{C\xb0\x9b~\xad\xc5\xecgT\xb0\xb3\xa2\xb1\xf3\xdd\xaeEs\xc5\xc9\xe0\x1a\x15\xd7\xda\xe8vwwW70\x10\xbay]\xc6=&\xe1\xc6viK\x0ex\xb0\xc3\xd1!\x81\x96A{I\xb1:\x18\xe2q\x1c@\xcb&\xf3L\xbd{\xb0\xbf\xca~\xc0n\t\x1d\x12\xed\x0e\x90W\xad\xedn`-\xd0\xa5F\xbd-rX\xec\xa0\x9b_\xd5;\xa6,`\xe3y\xd5\x02\xa0\x12\x85\xc0I\x8d\x0c\xfa\xda\'\x89\xb02\x8d}\xcbr\x1cL\xb1\xe1\x14\x80U\x94\xb6\x08\xfb\xa5\xb8u\x9d/\xcez\x8aD\xfa\xc2}\xcf\xf1\x98W4q(4\xe5\x94fG\xc4\x93\xfb8\xfa\xb7\xfc\x02\rd\xc8\xac\x17\xf0{\x83Uc\xc2\r\xe5\x02\x1d\xacn\xcb\xaal\xbb&\xef\xea&\xa0Ja%\x12\xa4:\x02\xca\x87,\xd0\x00\x17\x84uG$\xe2(\x0c\xb4\x884\x10D\\\x83\xacG\xcb\xe9c$\x12\x87\x0e\xa1\xa3\x04\xb3X\x169\x00\xc1\x18$6\x9a\xc2\xb95\x08\x82\x07\xd0\x03\xf6)\xb0*\xe6|8\xb3\xdf\x08~\x05\xeb\xa4\xf1\x04\xc3\xbb\n\x07\x98\x88\x86\x13M\xac\x01\xbfa\xd7\xa0\xaf-\xbf\xff\xc5!\xc2\xb5\xd5a\xb9\x14\xc3H*\xb4\xc2i\xb0\xcf\x8c\x15\xae\xba\x16`\xbd\x89\x80^\x07\xc1\x18\x92Q\x08\xba\xa9\xc1\'GKZ\x8fqj\x0e\x87\x98B\xdae\x1a\xc5\x9b}\x01\x87\x1fHC\x85\xd3KhS\x86\x94\xf9\xea\x0b&\xe3\x07\xd2|L\xa31\xad\x005\x10\xf8\xf4\x88\x83\x02&\xe1\xc3B\xf2\x00V\x86P\xa9z\x99p\x8f\x81\x94!\x18\x8c\x19\xa2\xf4dx\x1c\x1b\xb6\xe4\x9c\xb0a\x0b\x8e\xb1\xa9g\xb0efV\xd8\x14\xd8\xd9\x13l\xfa86\x05\x83Bdf\x84\r\xecLF#l\xd13\xd8\xb2h^\xd8\xc0\xce\x9e`\x8b\x8fc\xd3\x91\n\xe2\x17:t\x1e\x9d\x82\xc0\xce\xd4\x08Z\xf2\x0c\xb4,\x9c\x1740\xb31\xb4\xf48\xb4H\x9bYA\x8b\xc0\xca\xc6\xd0\xcc3\xd0\x0c\xf0\xbc\x19!\x03#S\xa3\x19\xdc\xcb\x8eC\x8b\x91\x80\xce\x07Z\x0cF\xa6\xe2,{2q3-\x99\xdey\x01\xa6\tB%\ndK0\xab\xf7m\xde=q\x8b\'\x19\xf2\xc9\x04\x17~F\xa0\x13C\x8f\xb7QT\x8c\x9f&R(i\x02sH\x91F\xb8\xd12\xe5X\xb7\x82I\xdc\x12\xfa\x9d\xfb\x02\xa0\x81\xc4j \t\xd28Q\x9c\xd3\x86S\x1c\xa8\xe2,A\xcd;\xdd}i5p\x10\xc7\xa4A\xf6\xc7HsL\x06\tKA\x9d\xf4\xa48"\x81\x8cHY\xbfS\x86?z\xcf\xe5`]`B\xb0\x1ad\xd3t\xe1\x14\x9d\x9f"\x85,\xe4\xcd\xa6\x95\x94[\xc6)\xbb\xf4\xbe\xd8\x14\xe2k\xf64/a\xed\x9b\xe2J\x0c\x97\xcb%,!\x13\xef\x9e\xfd\xa9\xa5u\x97\x94E\xbbh\xef\x8ae\xb9.\x97\xe2u\xce\x1f\xb7\xf6Y-\x0b\xf1\rfF\x7f\x14\xc7\xacmY\xab\x02?^z\xfc\xfa5\'zm\x13_\xfav\x81~\xbet%R\xdd\xc5~U\x06z\x7f\x18\x18g\x1c\x07\x19\x0c\x94\x19\x02\xeb)Gc+BY\xd8N\x02 A\x07Kl\xd7\x8f1\x06\x97\x956\x11\x05y\\\xc0\x10d\xd2\x82\xd3-\\\xd6\x05\xe5\xa5\xd2\x16\xe8n\xa14<\x1elz\x8d\xb4@?\x82\x19\xb6\xd2\x13A\xd4^\x10h\x10\xae\x1e\x02{Q\xa2h/\x0b\x04\xf7\xc2`\xd8\xe5\x9f\x90\xa6\x05[P\x81\x8c\xcdHK\xd0\xbd!c\x04\xf4\x14\x1e{\xe9\x16lU\xf6\xd17\xb7\x85L\x03\x05_\xf4!1z\x9f\xd0_\xaa\xf0\xd1O\x0bc\xb4"\x88YrH\x9d\xa2\xfab\x1c6\xfbI\xb9\x0c.\xa2\'ELP\xa4\xb1\xc6\xfc\xcb\x99R\xbc^3\x19\xf6B\xdc\n\x14\xd460>\xfdKT\xa7\x17\x89.\x7f\xa6p\x9b\x87\xc6\x92\xfd\x12\xf1\x9d\xed\xcf\xbfb\xad\xa9\xd0[\xd1/\x06\xbaM\xa6\xad\xc3%S\xd6\xfd\xf1#\xfa-\xd0\x11\x8b\xbb@\xbc\'R\xde\xf8\x8b\x8c72\x16\x86\xb60\xd0\xa9\x11\x05\x19\xf9;\xd0\xadT\xb6\xfe"5\xb8S\xf4\xaciK\x18\x83\x90\x94\xc2C\'\xff\x13\xdb\x9e\x9a\xeb\x8c\xc4\n\x86\xaaQ\xbc5\xf6\x1d\x80\xcf`\xf8(\xb7[\xdc\xc2Yhr\x0c-A\x15\xec\xcfCGY\x03\xfa0\xb4\xe1\xc1\xb1\xdb\xc2\x06P/\n\xd3\x93\x12M\xe2\xb9\x0f\xa4B\xdc\xa6\x00\x15*t\x10\x95.)\xab\x10\x86\x8b0K\xc0\xba\xc0d\x94\xdc\xbb\x8b\xf6.Q\xeb.z\xbf-r\xda\xdah\x0b\xf6U\xd1K\x03\xe3\x9d\xf1\x04\xbf\xa0\xef\x08\x87@\xc3[p\x92\x9cc\x9c\x87\\G\xb1\x87\x8e\xeb\x18?t5:\xea\xc4\xd5\xf0\xb3\xa8\xd7n\x83$U\xb2\xef\xabK\xdc\xf6\xc2\xc1\r\xa8\x0c\xed\x13\xa13p\xd7\x88\xfc\x8a\\\x80\xe4\xcd\x8ah\xec\xa5\xb7\x8e\xdfl\xeaW\xa0\x01\xac}g\xf7i"O\\m9\xe1\xae\x10u\x03o\xf9\xf2\x06t\x7f\x13\xf4\x9d?\xec\xcbR)\xf9\x0b\xd0\x97\x05\x1d\xf678\xb3\xd0\x97\xd2\xdf\x11\r\xa5\x9bG\xac\xd7Y\x917\x0b\xc5\xb2\xde,i]\xc7\x99G;1\xa9w#vw\xe8\xc8\xa5m\x1f\x121e\xafu\xf8\xc4\xa3/\xed\xae\xdc\xaa~@\xe7\xa4A\x9f"\xab~\xc3\x81B\xb4]\x8e\x9b}^\xd3\x0e|]\xee,\xca\xd8\xe9\x85\x07\x05\xf4\x1c\x9d^*\xcd\xa0k~\xaa\xd3\xebE\xc2\x9dpz\rP\x9epz\xcd\x07\x1b;\xbd\x86\xd8\xa6\x9d^\xb3\xc1f\x9d^Cl\xd3N\xaf\xf9`c\xa7\xd7\x10\xdb\xb4\xd3k>\xd8\xd8\xe95\xc46\xed\xf4\x9a\r6vz\r\xa1M;\xbd\xe6\x03\x8d\x9c^Ch\xd3N\xaf\xd9@c\xa7\xd7\x10\xda\xa4\xd3k>\xc8\xd8\xe95\x846\xe9\xf4\x9a\r\xb4\xbd\xd3k<q\xefi\xc9`+U\xa1\x0bB\xb9\xadT\x85\x1c\xf4S\xd8\xa7\x8a5N6\x87\xadTi\xdc\t\x02\xb7\x1d\xad\x89~&\xbc\x99zE\x87\xa5b\xafZ\x89\xfa\x9e\xceZ\x14\xb4\x19\xddp\xb4\xe0\x83\x1a\xf0\xf5\xae\\\xd2\x87\x1b>\xaa\xc1\xfc\x1dF\x868;vh\xcf\x92\xd2\xdd\x1d\x12~\xdc`\x16-\x1fSp\xa7\xf0J\xf6\xa3\xd8\xefwE#\xd6\x96\x08\xc3\xca\x07wpo\x89\xc0\xa6tDi\xf4\xa9\xe2\xf8\x0e\x97\x11\x0b+\xa6X\xee\x0f\xff\xd9\x9a\x8a\x8e\xf2\xa1\xcc\xf6x`]7S\x9b\xbdJ\xa7A\x92\xcc\x91\xf7\xe2\xb9\x1c\xf3\xe9\xc4\xf7%\xe2\x9d"\xbe\x03\x98\xa7\x98\xefl\xc0Y\xe6;\x04w\x82\xfa\xce\x05\x9c\xa3\xbeCp\'\xb8\xefl\xc0Y\xee;\x04w\x82\xfc\xce\x06\x9c%\xbfCp\'\xd8\xef\\\xc0Y\xf6;\xc4v\x82\xfe\xce\x06\x1b\xd3\xdf!\xb6\x13\xfcw.\xd8,\xff\x1db\x9b&\xc0\xb3\x81f\t\xf0\x10\xdb4\x03\x9e\x0b\xb6\x03\x03\x1e\xcf\xe0\x03\x82\xc2\xfcW\xa6f\xcf\x7f\x93\xdfB\x80\xf1T<\xf9\\\x0f\x1eX{\x9aP\xba\xe3\xc8\x11\x10H:\x07\xaa\xf1~B\xc0Nix@I\xb1{mp\xa7M\xe3m\x11H\xbb\xdc\xf0\xf9]b\x94\x11\xf9\xa3!\xb6aZ\x0b\x03\xa5w\xeb\'t"\x11b\xc9\xd1\x9c\xb8\x87XRdEg\x16S\xc7\x9be\xa0L\xda;\xa7\xafG\xa7_\x91\xd8f\xc0X\xed\x03\xeb\xd9\x14[\xf6\xe7\xb2\x08\x18\xd9\x89\xe2\xb1\x10[*Z\x12oW\xde\xbdK6\xc5te\xa6\xe6\xc9t%n\x16}:\xd3}\x91x\'\x98\xee\x10\xe6\t\xa6;\x1fp\xcctG\xe0\xa6\x99\xeel\xc0Y\xa6;\x027\xcdt\xe7\x03\x8e\x99\xee\x08\xdc4\xd3\x9d\x0f8f\xba#p\xd3Lw6\xe0\x98\xe9\x8e\xb0M3\xdd\xf9`#\xa6;\xc26\xcdtg\x83\x8d\x99\xee\x08\xdb$\xd3\x9d\x0f4f\xba#l\x93Lw6\xd8\xf6L\xf7\xc9\x0c~\xdc\xd9+5\xcd\xf7\xb1\x06\xaa\x18\t\xa0\xbc\x9fv\xd4@&q\xa0\xa2!\xd7=\\\x9d\xb1\xa7\xd6br\xf7\xe2\xad\xa9 `\xcfh\xd0v9\xfa{+\xf1X\xef\x1a\xbe\x01\xd4\x95w]]\xb4\x02?pT\xe1\xae\xd0\xe1\x15\xec#W\xfb\xec\x15V\xbc\x92\xbdF\x12\x8c\x17\xc4\xf0\xfeP\x83\xb7\xcb\xf0"n\nE(\xba$\\\xf2u\xbd\xca\xc7\x0b\xc0"\xbf\xaa\xef\x0br+S\xfdbS\xe4\xabI\xb6\x1ae\xa8\xcb\x19\xb2\xd5(\x0e\xe2O\'\xab/\x11\xee\x14Y\xed\xa3<\xc5Ug\x83\xcdr\xd5\x01\xb6\x13Tu.\xd8\x1cU\x1d`;\xc1Tg\x83\xcd2\xd5\x01\xb6\x13Du6\xd8,Q\x1d`;\xc1S\xe7\x82\xcd\xf2\xd4\x01\xb4\x134u6\xd0\x98\xa6\x0e\xa0\x9d`\xa9s\x81fY\xea\x00\xda4I\x9d\r2KR\x07\xd0\xa69\xea\\\xa0\x1d8\xeah\xe2\x1e\xd0\x92X\xc6x\xcf\x06\xf8)(#\xc1\xe3\xf5J\xe3E\x98\x1e=M\x9e\xbf\xab\x13\xcb\x8c\xbc\xb7\xd1\xc0\xd33\xbe\xac\x83\xe6\x0e\xa9\xa4"2\xbb\x00\xa1\xe82\x8eQ\xf6\xc8\xed\xeb/N\x13a\x15I0\xc14\x0b\xfa\xd7\xc7\xa5\xde\x9fy\xb0\x17\xc8\xdf\xfbR\xf3\xe9\x03\xf8\xcd\x97>\x1e\x9b\x96t\xe8ZJ\xbeB\xae\xbd\xb2\xc2#\x0e\x9eh;?\xf6(xC\x89\x1a\x8c\xdc\xec\x83\xcc\x8b\xf1N\x80\xd2:\x15P?\x0c\xb6\xe9\x9e\x1f\xefO0\xdb\x9a\x85\xb8\xf4~\xa8+<\xcc\x80\x8e\xe3K_\xd0\x1f\x15\x02\xfa\x8f\x8d=?\x11\xba\xf3\xbc\x89\xcdw\xe9}\x9b?B}.\x07g\x812L\xa2{||\x7f\xb88u\xf5\xd1\xdf\xa5\xf7\xef"\xf7\xf1D}s\xe9S\xce\x1ec=v\xbb*\xa1k\xe3I\x12H\xe3.\xc0D\xda\xc9d\x97\x12\x9f\xfd\xcd\xdeYy\xe0\xa7X\xe2Y\x0c0\x11tJ\xa3+\xbd\\\xf1kQu"o8\xae@\x96\xcf\xd1\xa2\xdb\xe4\x1d\xbc\xf2\xdbN\xd8bJX&d\xdev+\x9c\x9c\xae\xbd\xe3 \x8c\xdd\xf1plL}\xe0\xd0U\xddYsB\x8a\xa2Ar:\xd0\x0fv\x07\xa6\nM2\xb0\xd4\t\xdc\n\x96P\xd0\xcd\x86\xc0Q\x97\x0c\xdc\xeat\x0b\x9a\x8cq}\x83v\xd2\x02"X\xbe$\xee\x1d\x960W\xf96\xc7k;x\xb4\x9c@d`\x9dao\xd9\x14\xed\xef\x12Y\xb3(\x96\xb8\x85@;\x07R\xa31\xe2\xbd\x88]\xc5qm\x07K"\x0e>\xa2\x92"o\xc3o\x05-\xd9\x82 \xf8l\xac\xaac]\x03d\x84\x95H\x86\xe4tx\xc5\xe3}\xd1\xb4\xb0\xfa\xfb\xa9\xb8\xab\x9b\xae\xac\xae\xbf\xea\xf5\xcc\xf1\xe56\x1e\xa8\xf0N\xc6\xbc\x96`x\x84_\x99\xc1\xf2\xd8\xe1~(\xbb\x8dx\xdd\xe4e%\xdeV\x1fw\xcd\xe33\xb4\x9e(\xd4\x8b\x84~t\xc9\x92\xd1\xf5\xc01\xe6\xf3\xf2\xba\xc2;h9t\xc9\x1f\xbbM\xd1\x1c\'UR\xbe\xd8v>J\xaad|\x0cju\xbd-\xc4\xfb\xa6^\x17m[\xd6U\xbe=\xceE\xd0\xd1\xa2\xe6\x036\x8a4\xdeH}j\xce=\xa0\xe2\x9b\xbaj\x8b\xaa\xdd\xb5=\xc8\xca\xd0eM\xbc\xf2\x9a\xe0,\x8e\x1e\'j\xe7#N\xa6\x10\x06\'76\xda\xb0\xcb\x9e\xeeG\x10\xac4\xbf. K\xbd\x16\xea\xbfG\x17\x94D\xff_\n\x84E\xe3\x11G\xe4\x07\xfcK\xe5K\xf1\xc6\xdd\x0ec\x90)^\xe1AB\x81\xeb\\\xfb\x80\x94\xe7P\xf0\x9bc\xd7\xffPAP\xba\t\xcc\xc0\xc9(S\xbe\x9f\xc7O\xf7\x867\xf0\xe2\x84s\x9c\x94\'\xce\xc8\xd4>U\xa0\x18/rE"\x85Y\xa9g\xa0,A\xb8\x97h\xd1\x17\x89U\xc4\x17\x08Ok\x08~\x01\xeb\xaf\x17\x08,\x10O\x03\x11\xde\xde\xc5\xc4\xbd@\x8b\xe7ttZ \xab\xa2O\x95\xc8\xaah$\xd2XE\x03\x81\xb0\r\xb0\x953#\x12\x98\x1b\x15~M\x93\'\x02I\xa0v\xa1\xb2\xca_`JC\xaafs>\xb7\xe6l\x9e\xef7\xb1\xc6J\xd38F\\`\xce\xf0\xd3\x10\x8cP|/\x90\xf9\x82^\x1e \xfb\x0f\x82-=\xccT\x08\xdaRafM\xfe?\x02\x0c\x00.\xce\xb1\x1d\n\nendstream\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<<\n/ExtGState <<\n/GS1 8 0 R\n>>\n/Font <<\n/TT8 9 0 R\n/TT2 11 0 R\n/TT4 13 0 R\n/TT6 15 0 R\n>>\n/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]\n>>\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<<\n/OPM 1\n/Type /ExtGState\n/SM 0.02000\n/OP false\n/SA false\n/op false\n>>\nendobj\n9 0 obj\n<<\n/FirstChar 48\n/Widths [ 600 0 600 600 0 600 600 0 600 600 ]\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n/Type /Font\n/BaseFont /CourierNewPSMT\n/LastChar 57\n/FontDescriptor 10 0 R\n/Subtype /TrueType\n>>\nendobj\n10 0 obj\n<<\n/FontBBox [ -21 -680 638 1021 ]\n/StemV 42\n/Descent -300\n/XHeight -578\n/Flags 34\n/FontStretch /Normal\n/Ascent 832\n/FontName /CourierNewPSMT\n/Type /FontDescriptor\n/FontWeight 400\n/ItalicAngle 0\n/FontFamily (Courier New)\n/CapHeight 578\n>>\nendobj\n11 0 obj\n<<\n/FirstChar 32\n/Widths [ 250 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 333 333 0 0 0 333 250 0 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 333 0 0 0 0 500 0 722 667 722 722 0 611 0 0 389 0 0 667 944 722 778 611 0 722 556 667 722 0 0 0 722 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 500 556 444 556 444 333 500 556 278 0 556 278 833 556 500 556 0 444 389 333 556 500 722 0 500 ]\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n/Type /Font\n/BaseFont /TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\n/LastChar 121\n/FontDescriptor 12 0 R\n/Subtype /TrueType\n>>\nendobj\n12 0 obj\n<<\n/FontBBox [ -558 -307 2000 1026 ]\n/StemV 136\n/Descent -216\n/XHeight -546\n/Flags 34\n/FontStretch /Normal\n/Ascent 891\n/FontName /TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\n/Type /FontDescriptor\n/FontWeight 700\n/ItalicAngle 0\n/FontFamily (Times New Roman)\n/CapHeight 656\n>>\nendobj\n13 0 obj\n<<\n/FirstChar 32\n/Widths [ 250 0 408 0 0 833 0 0 333 333 0 0 250 0 250 0 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 278 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 667 667 0 0 556 0 722 333 0 0 0 0 722 722 556 0 0 556 611 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 444 500 444 500 444 333 500 500 278 278 500 278 778 500 500 500 500 333 389 278 500 500 722 0 500 ]\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n/Type /Font\n/BaseFont /TimesNewRomanPSMT\n/LastChar 121\n/FontDescriptor 14 0 R\n/Subtype /TrueType\n>>\nendobj\n14 0 obj\n<<\n/FontBBox [ -568 -307 2000 1007 ]\n/StemV 82\n/Descent -216\n/XHeight -546\n/Flags 34\n/FontStretch /Normal\n/Ascent 891\n/FontName /TimesNewRomanPSMT\n/Type /FontDescriptor\n/FontWeight 400\n/ItalicAngle 0\n/FontFamily (Times New Roman)\n/CapHeight 656\n>>\nendobj\n15 0 obj\n<<\n/FirstChar 47\n/Widths [ 278 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 ]\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n/Type /Font\n/BaseFont /ArialMT\n/LastChar 57\n/FontDescriptor 16 0 R\n/Subtype /TrueType\n>>\nendobj\n16 0 obj\n<<\n/FontBBox [ -665 -325 2000 1006 ]\n/StemV 88\n/Descent -211\n/XHeight 515\n/Flags 32\n/FontStretch /Normal\n/Ascent 905\n/FontName /ArialMT\n/Type /FontDescriptor\n/FontWeight 400\n/ItalicAngle 0\n/FontFamily (Arial)\n/CapHeight 718\n>>\nendobj\n17 0 obj\n<<\n/Length 3133\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nh\xde\xd4\x9bK\x8f\xe3\xb8\x11\x80\xef\xfe\x15\xc4\x02\x01\xa4\x00\xe6\x8a\x14II\xa7\x00\xc1\x06\x13\x0c\xb0@\x82\xf1m\xb0\x07\x8f[\xfd\xd8\xf1\xb4:\xb6;\x8d\xfe\xf7\xa9b\x95l\x8bvS\x9e[\n\x03\xd8zR\xf5U\xf1\xf1y\xec\xd6M\xed\xd4\xc3\xe2\xd7O_\x8cz\xd8/\xeaJ\xb7N\x05[\xe9\xe0\x94w\x95\xae\x95\xb3\xba\x0bj\xd7/\xee\x17\x7f_-~]\xad\xac2ju\xbf0VW\xb6\xeeT\x05\xff\xc6\xed\xdaj\xdb\xaa\xe0\xad\x0eV\xad~,*hz\xa9\xab\xcaz\xb5\xda,`\xc3\xa9\xd5\xdb\xe2k\xa1\x1a\xad\x94\xd6\xe5\xb2)\xf4\xfe\xad\\\xb6\xba+\xfa\xfeE\x1d\x1e{u_.M\xad\xdbb[.\x9d6\xc50\xec\xfeV\xfe\xb1\xfa\xbc\xf8\xc7j\x01!r\x84\xbeq\xda\xc6\x00\xbb$\xc0LXU\xd0\xa6\xad\xccy`\xb8\x17\x033\x96#kcd\x1a\x82\n\xda\x17\xeb\xedw5\xbc\x1e\xf6Ow}\xd9\xe9P\xc4\x08\x1f\x87\xd2C\xc0\xaf\xfb^\xc5\xc8\xe01\xa6\xf6\xf8\xc8\xd5o\xb1\xd5\xba\x99\xe2\x1e\x06\xb5V\x9b\xf5N\xbd`\xab\xaeX\x97V\xd7\xc5\xee;\xed\xf5w\xf4\xae\x9e\x80\x1c2^<\xc3;\xee\xe3\xb3\xf8\xdc\xae\x0c\xc5x\xfa\xbf\xf1\xee\xfe-\xee\x9ab\xfd~\xcc\x8f\xa6br\x8al\xa3\x9b\xab5\xfc8E\xde\x03\xe4Y\x8a0Cn\xccP\xe0\x0cu\x94\xa1\x87\xbe\x8c\xcf?\x94X&\xf5\xf4|\x18b\x1c^\xbb\xda\xd9S2\xc6\xfb\xbd\xe7\xfb\x87\x1d\xa6T\rXh\x0f$\x94\x9b+Ev\xad\x1d\t\xc2\xed\x08\xc6M\x10\xaa1|~\xbc\x81LV\xa5)\x8ee6&V$`\x87\x0bP\xe2\xef\nw6@\xd5@\xda;x\x1d\xe0\xf2\xfd\x1e\xc2|Y\xc7 ;\xed\xad1g\xe5\x0e#"\xa7\x08\xaa\x05)\x89\xe5\xad\xb1l^[,*\xee=\xa8-\xed\x0f\xe5\x12FIqP\xd09\x0e\x8ft\xb2\x8f\xf7\xa9\x1f\xa5\x81\xb2\xd2y\xbez\x1b\x8bm\x8b\xeb\xa5v5\xdcm\x7f\xb2\xd6.\xb4p\xf5\xf9X\x181\xac\x1dS\x05\xb5\x84Wx9e\xcbBdx\x18"j \xa0\xef\xea\xf5\x05*\ny\x82\xc0\xef\x867\x1c\xd2\x80ZS]wk`q\xc5\x0b\x1d\xb8R\xe2\xba\xedt\xdb\xfe\xe4@v\xd6\xe86\x9c\xf7Q\xcb\x91W\xdd\xb1\xc8\x10\x9b-\r\xbcj\x9cO`4\x1d\xab\x8d\x04\x81r\x8aC\xeb;t]\xec\x82\xc8\xd0\x15C\x1c\xf8\xb6\x88\xe3\xbd+\xee\xa0\x18\x10\xe1\xf4\x8e-\x8fO\xbe\xf4\x11+\xe5\x0b\xbaaG3\x02t\x9e\xda7\xa7.b\xc6\x19\xc1sn\xfb\xb2-\xd4K?\xbclq\xf6\xabi\x7fW\xe2\x93\x96\xd0\xe5^\x9e\xe8\xf0\x1d\x9f~Wq\x964|\x1af\xa5\x97\xf5\xfe\xa0\xde\x87\xd7\xeb=\xa2v\x90\xf0\xf6\'{D\xddx\x1cigy\x1d{Du\x1a<\xd0\'k\xc8k\xe0.\xb1\xde\x95qR\xea\xcb8\x94\xbf\xbdB\xc1\xb1\xc3\xbe\xf4t\xfc\x0eg\xb5\x00]\x02b\xc0y\xf0\xdb{lbD\x0fpcL\x18\xcc\xf8\xaeqg\xb3F\xc7\x8fn\x1a\x9e6\xd6{\x18\n\x05"+\xaac\x8d\xc9\xa8\xa1\xd9-\xcd\xd5\xdf\xb1G\xc6)\x9a6v\xc3+m<@\xbc\xa6xLN\xf7\xb1\xb4M\xd2\xc866\xed\xaf\xf5U\xdb\xb5\xc7\x9c\xde>\x1f\xd5uu\x96\xd4\x886\xf6V_sV]\xec\xa3-\xf6)\x8d\xd14\xd8i[z\xc3\xbd=.\x85uq\x80\x15r\x88\xf3HL%\xce\xa34\x87\xfa\xe2>\xce\x0f\x90\x9e5\x9fW=\xdf\xb4Y\xc7)\xa4%N\x0b7\xee\xd4\xd8G\x9d7g\x13u5\xa6\x9c\xbbh\x1c\xed\xd0\xc2c\x89\xbd\xfd\t\xb3\x16\xf3\x13;{\xac\xc3z\x07\xdd\x16\x9a\x86\x15q{\xf7\xf4\x1c\x9bmu\xe8\x9a\xe6\xca\xe4\xe8\xb8\x90\x0f\xccP\xd3\xb2\xb8[?\xf1\xdc\xc6S]2_^\xef\xdf\x16\x15#\xfcd\xff\xb6-\x14\xba\x9dLyGd\x7f\x9a\xf2L\xe1K=.\x10\xfb\x98\xf4x4Nk\x812O\xd8t\xfc>\xe6\xc9\xe2;\xce\x88P\x02H\xfe&^\xb1\xc6\x86\xb6k^\x19\xb1\x93\xb7\xf6\xac\x93\xdbn\xea\t\xbb\xd8\xb3]\xcc\xf9R\xc7\x15\xbf\xa3\x9c\xbb\x98\xf3GLM\x80\xa5\xa3\xc6f\xe9\xe4\xdd\xf9\x95\xcfq\x872\xec)\xd6\x97\xf5n\xd3s\x0b{\xb5\x7f\xa5\x13\x9bG\x18\x07\xeb\x03\x85\x15tU\xd7\xe7\xeb\x19F\xf55\x0e5\xbc\xba)`}~~\xa6\xcd\xe1\x80\xc5\xc6\xe6\x02>:\x9e\x1d\xf8\\\\\xc9z\xaahGk\x97\x1bc\x0b1\xb6\xe6\xac\x9e\xa7\x81\x15\x82\xd1\xcdQ7k(\xd9-6\xd7\xc1\xc8\x98H\xa6k\xc7q\xc5\xab@\xd0\xf8d\x98\x95\x14oh\x1a\x12\xbc\x17\x07\x08\x8c$\x1c2\re\x12\xbbv\xc4i\xe2XR\x9bG\xda\x8c}\x14G\xc1N\x1d\xaf\x86\x18\xd7\xe3\xf9(\xad\xb8v\x0fq\xc9\xd9)n{\xc0.\xd3\x16\xb4\x86\xf4\x90\x00\xd0\xa5\xc7\xb1\xadgz\xde\xb5\x8c\xd8\n\xdc\xed4\xd5\xdc\x98\x12\xd8\xd2M\x98\n\xae\x1b\x87_0\xdc\xc3\x03O6m\x9cl\xd0\xddb>L\xc1{\xd8\x05C\xb1\xde\xf2Z\x89\xfe\x8b\x900\\#T\x83\xf5\x8c+$\x1d\xed9_5\xf9+\xde\xb2\x89\xc3\xe2]\x9d\xae\x8f\x87\xef\xa2\xb2\x1a\x9a\x88X\xb7,\xcd\xda\\\x8cf:\xedV\xea\x13\xbc\x7f\x86\x8f\x1b\x7f*\xa3\xab\xa6So\xcaT\xeaw\xf5\xf5\x8fJ\xdd\xc1\xa9\'\xb5\xf8\x8f2\x94\t\x10?\r\xb3\x19\xa8\x9fvj\xf3#\x1e\xc44\xc0\xdc\xe0\x14$\x1a\x12\x01+\x14l\x82\xbc\xd0\xd6f\x81K+\xef\xe0\x14\x04}\x90\xae\xa6\xed\n\xaf\xa0\xcd%\x1do\x8f\r\x9c^\xe0\x9a\xd8x\xdc\xa9\xf8\xca*\xde\xfc\xed\xaf\x8b\x7f\xf3g&\xf7\xf1g&\xef\xb0\xd4\xa1\x89\nw.\xad\x15\x16\xac\xa8\xfeR\xae\xfe\x1c3r\xa25\x15\xcc\x01\xee\xff\x12\xf7\x1a\xa4\x81\xcf^)da\xaa\xebhXIAhP\xc0\x0b4\xfb\x01Z\xd7IB\xb3\x95\xbdD\xab\xaf\xa3Y\x07\x8b\x9f\x1c2_\xe1G\x88\x04\xcd}\x80\xd6yIh\xa0\xa9\x97h\xfe:\x1a~N\xb0A\x0c[\xed\xc0mm\xca\x16>`\xeb\x8c(\xb6\xce]ak\xae\xb39X\xea\x05\xb19T\xf4\x0b\xb6\xf6\x03\xb6\xb6\xc1\xab\xc4\xb0u\x15~\xaaH\xd8\xba\xebl\xbe\xf6\x92\xd8<xbwe\xdd\xfe@JX\xc1\xa0ov\x12\xe0H\xbc\xa0"\xed\x89mF\xb7\x84\xa0\xb1nM\xd1ftK\n\x1a\xe9\xd6\x14mF\xb7\x84\xa0\xb1nM\xd1\xf2\xba%\x85\x8cuk\x8a\x96\xd7-)h\xac[S\xb4\x19\xdd\x12\xc26\xea\xd6\x94mF\xb7\xa4\xb0\xb1nM\xd9ftK\x08\xdb\xa8[S\xb6\x19\xdd\x92\xc2\xc6\xba5e\x9b\xd1-)F\xc2\xba\x95\xae\xdbY\xdd\xf2\x1d\xa8\x89\x18\xdd\xf2m\x87\xff\x99y\x9bnIA#\xddJ\xd0\xf2\xba%\x06-\xeaV\x82\x96\xd7-)h\xa4[\tZV\xb7\xc4\x90\x91n%hY\xdd\x12\x83F\xba\x95\xa0\xe5uK\n\x1b\xebV\xc2\x96\xd7-1l\xa4[\t[^\xb7\xa4\xb0\xb1n%ly\xdd\x12\xc3F\xba\x95\xb0\xe5uK\x8c\x91\x90n]\xac\xdby\xdd\xc2A*G\xb7\xa0k\xb6\xf6\xf4\x95\xf0\x9cp\t\x81c\xe1J\xe1f\x94K\n\x1c)W\n7#]B\xe0X\xbaR\xb8\xbcvIac\xedJ\xe1\xf2\xe2%\x05\x8e\xc5+\x85\x9bQ/!t\xa3z\xa5t3\xf2%\x85\x8e\xe5+\xa5\x9b\xd1/!t\xa3~\xa5t3\x02&\x85\x8e\x05,\xa5\x9bQ0)\x96\xc2\nv\xb9\x92\xe7%\xac2\xdaY1\x16\xe6\xba\x06\x7f\x9fw\xa3\x83Ia#\tK\xd8f\x14L\x0c[t\xb0\x84m\xc6\xc0\xa4\xb0\x91\x82%ly\x01\x13\x83F\x06\x96\xb0\xe5\xfdK\x0c\x1b\tX\xc26\xa3_R\xe0\xd8\xbf\x12\xb8\x19\xfb\x12\x03G\xfa\x95\xc0\xcd\xc8\x97\x148\xb6\xaf\x04n\xc6\xbd\xc4\xc0\x91|%p3\xea%\xc6M\xc8\xbd.\x16\xf0\xacy9\xef\xb5\tr\xcc\x0b\xa2\xaen5/1ll^S\xb6\xbcy\xc9a#\xf3\x9a\xb2\xe5\xcdK\x0c\x1b\x9b\xd7\x94-k^r\xd0\xd8\xbc\xa6lY\xf3\x92\xc3\xc6\xe65e\xcb\x9b\x97\x18\xb8\xd1\xbc\xa6py\xf3\x92\x03\xc7\xe65\x85\xcb\x9b\x97\x18\xb8\xd1\xbc\xa6py\xf3\x92\x03\xc7\xe65\x85\xcb\x9b\x97\x1c7a\xf3J\x17\xf0\xbcyU\x8d\xa0\xdfy\xb9*\xfeQ\xf6\x8d\xe2%\x04\x8d\xbdk\x8a6\xe3]R\xd0H\xbb\xa6h3\xda%\x04\x8d\xadk\x8a\x96\xb7.)d,]S\xb4\xbctIAc\xe7\x9a\xa2\xcd8\x97\x10\xb6Q\xb9\xa6l3\xca%\x85\x8d\x8dk\xca6c\\B\xd8F\xe1\x9a\xb2\xcd\x08\x97\x146\xf6\xad)\xdb\x8coI1\x12\xd6\xadt\xdd\xce\xeaV\x1d\x8c\xf6bt\xab\xf6\r\xfe\xa7\xe3m\xba%\x05\x8dt+A\xcb\xeb\x96\x18\xb4\xa8[\tZ^\xb7\xa4\xa0\x91n%hY\xdd\x12CF\xba\x95\xa0euK\x0c\x1a\xe9V\x82\x96\xd7-)l\xac[\t[^\xb7\xc4\xb0\x91n%ly\xdd\x92\xc2\xc6\xba\x95\xb0\xe5uK\x0c\x1b\xe9V\xc2\x96\xd7-1FB\xbau\xb1n\xe7u\xcb\x04\xfc\x11\xbe\x18\xdf2F\xb7\xb7~\xaf(\x86\x8d\x85k\xca6#\\b\xd8\xc8\xb8\xa6l3\xc6%\x85\x8d\x95k\xca\x96W.1h\xec\\S\xb6\xbcs\x89ac\xe9\x9a\xb2\xcdH\x97\x14\xb8\xd1\xba\xa6p3\xd6%\x06\x8e\xb5k\n7\xa3]R\xe0F\xef\x9a\xc2\xcdx\x97\x188\x16\xaf)\xdc\x8cx\x89q\x136\xaft\x01\xcf\x9a\x97\r\x9dn\xe4\xfc\xa2\xcb\x06\xafC{\xf3_4\x8a\xa1#\xf7\xba\xa0\xcb\xdb\x97\x1c\xbah_\x17ty\xff\x12CG\xfeuA\x97509pd`\x17tY\x07\x93CG\x0evA\x97\xb701xla\x17xy\x0f\x93\x83G\x1ev\x81\x97711xlb\x17xy\x17\x93\x83G.v\x81\x97\xb719\xbeB6veI\xcf\xfb\x98\x85\xc7\xb4r|\xcc\x1a\xed\xaa\xdb}L\n\x1d\xfbXJ7\xe3cb\xe8\xc8\xc7R\xba\x19\x1f\x93B\xc7>\x96\xd2\xe5}L\x0c\x1c\xfbXJ\x97\xf711t\xecc)\xdd\x8c\x8fI\xc1\x1b},\xc5\x9b\xf111x\xecc)\xde\x8c\x8fI\xc1\x1b},\xc5\x9b\xf111x\xecc)\xde\x8c\x8f\x89\xf1\x15\xf6\xb1\xcb%\x9d\x94\xc5\xd4\xba\x0b`4\xf1\x1e\xde\xae\x8d\x0eV5pK\x15\xbf\xca\\\xea\xaa\xf2N R\n>>\n/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]\n>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 19\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000009 00000 n \n0000000074 00000 n \n0000000175 00000 n \n0000000224 00000 n \n0000000365 00000 n \n0000000508 00000 n \n0000004748 00000 n \n0000004880 00000 n \n0000004967 00000 n \n0000005168 00000 n \n0000005423 00000 n \n0000005890 00000 n \n0000006160 00000 n \n0000006616 00000 n \n0000006880 00000 n \n0000007085 00000 n \n0000007328 00000 n \n0000010535 00000 n \ntrailer\n<<\n/Size 19\n/Root 3 0 R\n/Info 2 0 R\n>>\nstartxref\n10668\n%%EOF\n' (<type 'str'>)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback? It's nice to know that a `UnicodeDecodeError` happend somewhere but we can't help much unless we know where exactly it happened.

Comment: @koniiiik Absolutely. Added to original post.

Comment: I have tried using django's update() statement which works better but is still not giving the desired result. Substituting in: ABC.objects.all().update(pdf_printed="1") updates all records in the database (and displays the desired pdf object correctly) so need to figure how to use a filter instead of all for the specific record that has just been printed to the response object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Django doesn't support storing binary data in the database. I guess you inserted your data some other way. Anytime you call `save()` on your model containing binary data, you'll get a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

Anyway, as you state in your comment, using `QuerySet.update` works (since the value of this field isn't submitted to the database). If your model has the auto-generated `id` `AutoField`, you can try something like this as a workaround:

```
ABC.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(pdf_printed='1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on django/binary. I am using python and elixir to stuff the objects into the database. This filter works perfect. I was missing the pk=obj.pk filter (was trying pk=self.pk but that didn't work). Thanks again!